# Is it possible to use fetch request with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, ecmascript-6, fetch

I'm a little confused why fetch doesn't seem to be working properly and why Angular's $http.get does work in this case. My fetch request is going through and I can see that I'm creating the array I need to populate some images. But it isn't populating anything on my HTML page. If I call the function twice after a bit of a delay, it does seem to be working. And if I change it to $http.get it also works. This is my code for the fetch:

```
$scope.getPhotos = (url) => {
fetch(url).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(json => {
    $scope.photoArray = json.photos;
    console.log($scope.photoArray);
}).catch(err => {
    alert('Error');
});
}
```

Comment: can I have any reference for fetch request?

Comment: @VeeraBhadraRao Hey. Do you mean why I want to use it over http? Main reason is I think it's cleaner, especially when handling 404 errors.

Comment: @papernemesis Angular 1.x I'm guessing? You need to [trigger a digest](http://www.codingeek.com/angularjs/angular-js-apply-timeout-digest-evalasync/) somehow within your `.then`/`.catch` callbacks

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `fetch` is asynchronous action you should trigger digest cycle after it finishes in order to refresh the view with updated data.

You can do it via `$scope.$apply()` method.

Angular `http` method triggers digest cycle automatically under the hood, so you don't need to bother it when use this method.